# A section title immediately preceding a longtblr goes into the lower margin and overlaps the page number (and might even go lower)

Tags: margins, tabularx, page-breaking, tabularray, longtabu

Feeding `latex` or `pdflatex` with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
Text

%%% For tabularray:
\vspace*{122.63ex}%%% The lengthy section title overlaps the page number; this is wrong.  With .01ex more, the lengthy section title correctly goes to the next page.
%%% For tabularx:
%\vspace*{107.55ex}%%% The lengthy section title doesn't overlap the page number; this is correct. With .01ex more, the lengthy section title correctly goes to the next page.

Text
\section{Lengthy section title}
\SetTblrInner[longtblr]{rowsep=0pt}\begin{longtblr}[label=none]{@{}lX@{}}
%\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lX@{}}
short symbol 1 & long, multi-line explanation 1\\
short symbol 2 & long, multi-line explanation 2
\end{longtblr}
%\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: output with an overlap]

on the bottom of the first page. In particular, the section title “Lengthy section title” overlaps the page number “1”. This is wrong.

To find the source of the error, we tried to reproduce the issue with *tabularx* instead of *tabularray*—we failed (see the comments in the input above). Therefore, it's probably *tabularray* that has a bug in this regard.

Here's a shorter and clearer (but meaningless) document exposing the same bug:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
Text

\vspace*{122.63ex}

Text
\section{Lengthy section title}
\begin{longtblr}[label=none]{l}
  table
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

In my non-minimal example (I cannot provide it—my apologies), the section title even completely vanishes from the page probably because the title goes too low.

In https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/454, we kindly ask for a bug fix.

Here at TeX.SE, we kindly ask for a workaround or an alternative package that would provide us with a replacement for the `longtabu` environment (from the late *tabu* package) that allows for both a page break and automatic width setting of one column.

In a non-minimal example, the column specification `{@{}lX@{}}` is the only thing we need. The first column is going to be narrow (at most a few symbols per table cell). The second column contains the explanations of the symbols; at least one of these explanations spans multiple lines. In our most pressing non-minimal example, our table is not very long – we expect at most one page break in it. (In other examples, the table can go up to 10 pages.)